# static_assert usage in C++ vs C

Tags: c++, c, static-assert

This is a part of a huge project, so I post an excerpt from a cc file (only one static_assert is needed in the real code, I just experimented with it):

```
namespace large
{

static_assert(sizeof(void *) == 4, "64-bit code generation is not supported.");  // A

namespace fake_n
{
  static_assert(sizeof(void *) == 4, "64-bit code generation is not supported.");  // B
}

class fake_c
{
  static_assert(sizeof(void *) == 4, "64-bit code generation is not supported.");  // C
};

void fake_f()
{
  static_assert(sizeof(void *) == 4, "64-bit code generation is not supported.");  // D
}

}  // namespace large
```

gcc9 reports the following errors (correspondingly in A,B,C,D cases):

```
A,B : error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token

C : error: expected identifier before 'sizeof'
  : error: expected ',' or '...' before 'sizeof'
  : error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of '_Static_assert' with no type [-fpermissive]

D : error: '_Static_assert' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'static_assert'?
```

The last error made me think that the problem is with <assert.h> included somehow (through a long chain of includes). I found it and removed "#include <assert.h>", after that all errors are gone.

Questions:

1. What's the meaning of erros in cases A,B,C ?
2. Most important: how to handle in general situation with mixing C and C++ files?
   What if I can not remove (or even find) the corresponding <assert.h> ? How can I tell compiler to use C++ version of static_assert, not C macro?

Thank you!

Comment: Where's the C version in question? This is all C++-only code. If you include `<assert.h>` you might end up in trouble.

Comment: @tadman I meant C macro "static_assert" in <assert.h> , see https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Static_assert

Comment: Seems to work fine here: https://godbolt.org/z/Ys5oqYG96.  Maybe there is something wrong with your system's headers?  What OS and version?  Does it fail if you `#include <assert.h>` only, or is something else needed for a MRE?

Comment: @tadman Yes, this is the second part of my question - how to prevent trouble like tis?

Comment: The `<assert.h>` here on Ubuntu has its `#define static_assert _Static_assert` wrapped inside `#if !defined __cplusplus` so there's no problem.  If yours doesn't then it may be broken.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, I'd expect something like "#if !defined __cplusplus". I'll check <assert.h>. I believe it's only assert.h since the issue is gone after it was removed.

Comment: Anyway this also suggests that `#undef static_assert` after your `#include`s may be an easy workaround.

Comment: It seems in answer to your question #1 that `#define static_assert _Static_assert` is precisely the cause of your errors in all cases: https://godbolt.org/z/Paav63srq.  If you really wanted you could work out why it's a syntax error in each case, with `_Static_assert` being an identifier with no special meaning to C++, but it seems like a waste of time.

Comment: @NateEldredge The identifier `_Static_assert` is sort of special in the sense that it is reserved to the language implementation, and thus C++ programs may not declare it (or else behaviour is undefined) and the language implementation may declare it (with no particular meaning / behaviour specified for it by the C++ language).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Something in one of your headers appears to be doing `#define static_assert _Static_assert`, which fails in C++ because `_Static_assert` is a (reserved) identifier with no special meaning; in particular it doesn't perform a static assertion.  I get the same errors in [an example](https://godbolt.org/z/Paav63srq) by manually adding `#define static_assert _Static_assert`, and similar ones if I do `#define static_assert foobar`.

   This macro should be in `<assert.h>` when compiling as C, but a properly written `<assert.h>` should wrap it in `#ifndef __cplusplus` so that it doesn't apply to C++ sources.  So I suspect either:

   - Your system's `<assert.h>` is broken
   - Your compiler is confused about what language it's compiling (unlikely because then `namespace` etc would also be syntax errors)
   - Something else in your tangle of headers (or command-line compilation options) is being naughty and causing `#undef __cplusplus` or something like that.  If you've found the place where `<assert.h>` is included, you could try and track down the issue with strategic insertions of

```
#ifndef __cplusplus
#error Aargh
#endif
```

2. Normally you shouldn't have to do anything.  Properly written system headers will support C++ via appropriate `#ifdef`s, and work correctly when included into C++ programs.

   If you have a header from some third-party library that is written as C only and doesn't support C++, then you have some work to do to adapt it (or complain to its vendors).  That's a project beyond the scope of this answer.  Wrapping everything in `extern "C"` is a start but only a start.

Answer (score 0):

> 2. Most important: how to handle in general situation with mixing C and C++ files?

You can link C++ translation units compiled with a C++ compiler together with C translation units compiled with a C compiler. You can write header files by using the common subset of the languages. You can use macros to vary the declarations where necessary - most commonly to add C linkage specifier to the declarations when included in C++.

> How can I tell compiler to use C++ version of static_assert, not C macro?

Use a standard conforming C++ language implementation and there is no problem. Here is your example program working in GCC 9: https://godbolt.org/z/hEsMT8W93